# Why don't my small code changes take effect in appengine (GAE/GWT)? (onModuleLoad() not happening?!)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm just starting a new GAE project, and I see they've done some sprucing up of the SDK since I used it last.  In `my_server.java`, they've got a line of code near the top of onModuleLoad() that looks like this:

```
final Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
```

I changed it to look like this:

```
final Button sendButton = new Button("Send-X");
```

But the change doesn't take.  In fact, I added a log line:

```
log.log(Level.INFO, "button set");
```

and that doesn't show in the console, either.  This leads me to believe that my `onModuleLoad()` isn't happening.  Yet the old button ("Send") appears when I run the server (locally) and, when I click it, all of the handler code seems to be happening correctly.

Before you tell me to clear my caches, I should probably tell you about my follies there, too.

- I cleared the browser caches (tried with both Chrome and Safari.)
- I restarted the server.
- I even quit & relaunched Eclipse, just to be sure!
- Then I found some cache files in `war/`, so I got rid of them, too.
- This led to me now getting this message on server start:

  [WARN] No file found for: /my_server/F257245F8761687253A53003BCDAB6A7.cache.html

So, while my **REAL** question is: how do I get my code changes (like rename the button) to take, it looks like I've got a few smaller problems (caching, triggering onModuleLoad()) that I'll need help with, first.

Thanks!

Comment: Does other code changes take effect?

Comment: So far, I've not been able to affect code changes (including log().)  My HTML changes DO take effect.  I'm sure it's just some caching/restart thing or similar that I'm missing, but I'm not seeing it.  Keep in mind, I'm starting with the default project, so I don't have much functionality of my own, yet.

Comment: Did you try to rebuild your project (Project -> Clean -> all)?

Comment: Did Clean All.  Did Rebuild all.  Did rebuild GWT.  Tried with both Build-automatic on & off.

Comment: This sounds like GWT, not App Engine.

Comment: I'm getting this often with gwt and appengine. It seems that GWT javascript files are not uploaded. All other static files (html, images, etc..) are ok. For me it works to delete `target` directory and retry.

Comment: Ok, thanks all.  +1 to Nick & Peter for the hints to get me going.  Turns out I didn't want GWT at all, but it just came along as the default with the latest SDK.  (Or maybe I checked it, not knowing better.)  Either way, I just remade project without, and now I'm back to my old familiar GAE and everything works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i know the poster of the question has moved on however for the sake of others who might stumble upon this ...

in GWT for your changes to make it to the browser your Java code needs to be compiled to JavaScript. you can do this 1 of 2 ways.

1) perform a full GWT Compile. in eclipse you can right click the project -> Google -> GWT Compile. this will place all the js in your webapp dir. Then run|deploy your project and access it via a web browser

2) run in GWT Dev Mode which will compile only the java classes you need on the fly. its often easier to develop this way as this method supports client side breakpoints. in eclipse right click the project -> Run As|Debug As -> Web Application. then be sure to access your application on the URL that GWT gives you. The url will look something like http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 as long as your running your app with this url you can make java changes and just refresh the relevant portion of your app (in browser) to see the changes.

Comment: I had moved on, but thanks for the excellent answer!  And welcome to Stack Overflow :)